# Setting options for kendo grid with ko bindings

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, kendo-grid

I'm trying to follow instructions from this page: https://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html for binding a kendo grid to a knockout observable array. I think it works fine, but the method to specify grid options in that link is either:
1. Declaratively in the html
2. Via setting global options in ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options

Thing is, what I really want is to be able to specify those options SPECIFIC to this grid only, but do it in the javascript file (I'm using typescript if it helps).

The reason why I want to do it is because for the more advanced settings like selection listener etc, it's much easier to do it in typescript because it would have access to the parent object's methods and what not.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following fiddle something that you could use: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/empie/1nsxveom/)

Kendo grid Html:

```
<div data-bind="kendoGrid: gridOptions"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var grid = {
  data: false,
  dataSource: {
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
      read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
   }
    pageSize: 50,
    serverPaging: true,
   ...
  }


ko.applyBindings({
  gridOptions: grid
});
```